# How or when the init method of Super is called in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have components like a component which extend `components.pdf` like

```
<cfcomponent extends="components.pdf" >
 <cffunction name="generate" access="public" >
  <cfscript>
   config = {
    .....
   };
   oWriter = CreateObject("component","writers.pdf").init( config );
  </cfscript>
 </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

within generate function in initilize `oWriter` component with some settings.

After the `oWriter` component's init method is called I thought it contains the config options which i set. But when I dump the config struct within oWriter methods, I get the settings/options which were set in `components.pdf`

How these setting/config are over writting ?

Comment: 1.) Could you include your code for the dump? 2.) You may want to consider scoping config and oWriter. By default CF has those variables exist component wide

Comment: How does the writers.pdf constructor (`init`) look like? We need all affected components here. Please add the relevant code of `components.pdf` and `writers.pdf` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Let us call the component you have defined above: PdfGen. The behaviour you are getting is because the variable config is only defined within the context of PdfGen. Hence config exists as a property of the oWriter object only as long as the generate() function is alive. After the generate function's end-tag runs, config will cease to exist as a field of oWriter or of any other writer.pdf object.

You can achieve the result you want as follows. Redefine the above component (which I call PdfGen) as:

```
<cfcomponent extends="components.pdf" >
 <cffunction name="generate" access="public" returntype="any">
  <cfscript>
   config = {
    configKey = "some value"
   };
   oWriter = CreateObject("component","writers.pdf").init(config);
   return oWriter;
  </cfscript>
 </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Then define the *writers.pdf* along these lines:

```
<cfcomponent>

<!--- Component instance variable. Every writers.pdf object (defined through init) will have it--->
<cfset config = "">

<cffunction name="init" access="public" returntype="any">
<cfargument name="configArg" >
<cfset config = arguments.configArg>
<cfreturn this>
</cffunction>

<cffunction name="getConfig" access="public" returntype="any">
<cfreturn config >
</cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

The CFM page to test this will be something like:

```
<cfset writer=createobject("component","PdfGen").generate()>
<cfdump var='#writer.getConfig()#'>
```